# Is the source code of the online tour available?

Tags: source-code, javascript

For Oneiric Ocelot launch, there was an awesome Tour created for showcasing how Ubuntu especially Unity works.

The [Ubuntu Online tour](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/en/) actually mimics a whole desktop and to a greater extent behaves a lot like using Unity in real.

My question is where is the source code for this located? I know I can do view source, but scraping information and trying to join them is not a feasible solution. If the whole code is present somewhere, it would be highly beneficial for the JavaScript community

[image: The real desktop emulation in Ubuntu Tour]

[image: Welcome window of Ubuntu Unity Tour]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original answer:** Yep, you can get it on Launchpad [here](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tour).

**Edit:** It seems I linked to the wrong tour. The one from my original answer seems to be a desktop version that you would run on Ubuntu, whereas the one the OP is seeking is an online emulation of the Ubuntu desktop. As has been pointed out by user27777, the code for the online version can be found [here](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-online-tour).

Answer (score 11):

Yep, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-online-tour. This link leads to the Ubuntu Online tour.